# Why I had executed sigemptyset before sigaction, but sometimes the SIGALRM is blocked

Tags: signals

I had executed 'sigemptyset' before 'sigaction', but the SIGALRM is blocked.

But if I execute 'sigprocmask' to unblock SIGALRM, the SIGALRM is not blocked.

the part of codes as follow:

```
struct sigaction sa;
memset( & sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
sa.sa_handler = sigpipe_handler;
if (sigemptyset( & sa.sa_mask) < 0) {
  printf("sigemptyset fail! errno=%d, error info<%s>.\n", errno, strerror(errno));
}#
ifdef SA_INTERRUPT sa.sa_flags |= SA_INTERRUPT;#
endif
if (sigaction(signum, & sa, NULL) < 0) {
  printf("sigaction fail! errno=%d, error info<%s>.\n", errno, strerror(errno));
}–
```

Comment: the part of codes as follow:

  struct sigaction sa;

  memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
  sa.sa_handler = sigpipe_handler;

  if (sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask) < 0)
  {
    printf("sigemptyset fail! errno=%d, error info<%s>.\n", errno, strerror(errno));
  }

#ifdef SA_INTERRUPT
    sa.sa_flags |= SA_INTERRUPT;
#endif

if (sigaction(signum, &sa, NULL) < 0)
  {
    printf("sigaction fail! errno=%d, error info<%s>.\n", errno, strerror(errno));
  }

Answer (score -1):

seems  SIGALRM default shielded?

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be added as comment.